# How do I avoid repetitive checking in my recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

For those people already read my last post, I do have a different solution for this. Please don't just walk away.

This is an assignment question from school (Sorry for the long story, I already tried shorten it)

I tend to order food based on how much money I have on me.  I like to tip at least 15% regardless of service (I do enough evaluating performance in any given week already) and I hate the whole process of giving my money, waiting for the waitress to come back with the change the trying to find the correct change to make a proper tip.  What I do is examine the menu for the combination of foods that best matches the money I have on me. When I say best matches, I mean closest to 15% without going under, and I only pick each food item once. As you can imagine it takes me a bit of time to compute all of this so I want you to make a method that I can use.

The method only has to work for the following menu:

```
Bandera Pizza Bread 6.49
Boston's Pizza Bread    5.35
Garlic Twist Bread  7.49
Single Order    5.35
Sun-Dried Tomato Bruschetta 6.99
Three Cheese Toast  6.35
Double Order wings  16.49 
Starter Size wings  8.99 
Cactus Nachos   10.29
Baked Ravioli Bites 8.49
Southwest Quesadilla    9.25
```

Create a method called selectFood that takes the amount of money I have as a parameter, outputs the selections on the screen and returns the percentage tip I will be leaving rounded to one decimal place. Don't worry if there is more food than two people can eat, I often go out with larger groups.

Some example output:

```
Best order for $10.00 is:Baked Ravioli Bites
The tip is 17.79%

Best order for $20.00 is:Sun-Dried Tomato Bruschetta, Cactus Nachos
The tip is 15.74%

Best order for $60.00 is:Bandera Pizza Bread, Boston's Pizza Bread, Three Cheese Toast, Double Order wings, Starter Size wings, Baked Ravioli Bites
The tip is 15.03%

Best order for $190.00 is:Bandera Pizza Bread, Boston's Pizza Bread, Garlic Twist Bread, Single Order, Sun-Dried Tomato Bruschetta, Three Cheese Toast, Double Order wings, Starter Size wings, Cactus Nachos, Baked Ravioli Bites, Southwest Quesadilla
The tip is 107.58%
```

My teacher has a restriction - we are not allowed to use an arraylist.

Here's my newest try:

```
import java.util.*;

class MethodAssign7{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        boolean[] took = {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false};
        double money = 70.0;
        //System.out.println(selectFood(money/1.15,took));
        selectFood(money,took);
        System.out.println(closest/money*100+15);
    }
    static double closest = 10000.0;
    static void selectFood(double money, boolean[] took){
        String[] food = {"Bandera Pizza Bread","Boston's Pizza Bread","Garlic Twist Bread","Single Order","Sun-Dried Tomato Bruschetta","Three Cheese Toast","Double Order wings","Starter Size wings","Cactus Nachos","Baked Ravioli Bites","Southwest Quesadilla"};
        double[] costs = {6.49,5.35,7.49,5.35,6.99,6.35,16.49,8.99,10.29,8.49,9.25};

        if(money<5.35){
            if(money<closest){
                closest = money;
            }
        }
        else{
            for(double d: costs){
                if(money-d*1.15>0){
                    //System.out.println(money-d);
                    selectFood(money-d*1.15,took);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /*static void printSelections(double money, boolean[] took){
        String[] food = {"Bandera Pizza Bread","Boston's Pizza Bread","Garlic Twist Bread","Single Order","Sun-Dried Tomato Bruschetta","Three Cheese Toast","Double Order wings","Starter Size wings","Cactus Nachos","Baked Ravioli Bites","Southwest Quesadilla"};
        double[] costs = {6.49,5.35,7.49,5.35,6.99,6.35,16.49,8.99,10.29,8.49,9.25};

        if(money<5.35){
            if(money==closest){
                print the choices by using took
            }
        }
        else{
            for(int i=0;i<costs.length;i++){
                if(money-costs[i]*1.15>0 && took[i]!=true){
                    took[i]=true;
                    //System.out.println(money-d);
                    selectFood(money-costs[i]*1.15,took);
                }
            }
        }
    }*/
}
```

I'm trying to solve the percentage part of the question first with dynamic programming, I can get the percentage answer with my program, but it takes too long for money input above 60. I tried to addin the boolean list "took" to indicate which ones are already picked but it did not work at all and got me confused :(

All the parts that's commented out are for the output of selections of food. And I know my selectFood method is only void right now and won't return value, but I think that's easier to fix. All I care right now is how do I get this percentage part working.

Thank you for your time reading my question, if you can help me I would appreciate it very much or if you don't get what I'm asking please leave a comment to tell me.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i have changed my title.

Comment: Does this sound good to you? I really have a hard time to explain my problem in just the title.

Comment: The new title is a good question.  Note it is not a *requirement* to make the *title* itself a question.  In fact, I will often edit a title of "How do I do X with Y?" to just "Do X with Y", then copy/paste the full question down to the end of the post.  Won't touch this one, which is good as-is.  -- Unfortunately I cannot now remove my close vote, but it won't matter, since others won't add a vote.  Good luck with the question, hope you get a good answer. :)

Comment: @cookcook: You're not understanding.  His beef with the question wasn't so much the title, as it was that *you didn't clarify the question* -- in the title *or* in the body.  Now that that's fixed, though... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple version of this is that you start with an amount of money, x. At least a certain amount of this will be required as a tip, which we will call t. That effectively means that you want to spend as much money as you can, without going over (x - t).

What you want to do then, is define your targets:

```
    double totalMoney = 190.0;
    double minimumTip = totalMoney/115*15;
    double targetMoney = totalMoney - minimumTip;
```

I'll assume that you have the required data structures, like so:

```
    MenuItem[] items = new MenuItem[]
    {
        new MenuItem("Bandera Pizza Bread", 6.49),
        new MenuItem("Boston's Pizza Bread", 5.35),
        [...]
    };
```

Now we want to search recursively for the best possible combination of these items, such that the total cost of the selected items is maximized while always remaining less than targetMoney.

Each branch of the recursive tree will represent one combination of products that I could purchase. This is the key difference between my solution and yours. At the first branch of the tree, I will evaluate two possibilities - either I will purchase "Bandera Pizza Bread", or I will not. At the second level of branches, I will evaluate whether I should purchase "Boston's Pizza Bread", or not. At each recursive call, I only need to know whether I still have any money left to spend (at which point I look at the next item down the list) or whether this order has 'overspent', at which point I give up on this combination (since buying anything else will just make it even more expensive!).

To reduce the number of arrays I need to create/discard, I'm using an integer "selected" as a bit field specifying which items I have decided to purchase on this branch. If a bit is 1, then I have chosen to purchase this item. If a bit is 0, then I have chosen not to purchase this item. You could get the same effect using arrays of booleans, but there would be a lot of array manipulation getting in the way of the actual algorithm I'm demonstrating.

I've also created class variables for the best case:

```
int    bestPurchaseSet = 0;
double bestCost = 0;
```

You don't *have* to do this, you can pass your results around with parameters and return types, but it makes the code less heavy this way.

So then, the recursive function looks a bit like this:

```
public void search(MenuItem[] items,
                   int        selected,
                   int        depth,
                   double     currentCost,
                   double     maxCost)
{
    if(currentCost > maxCost)
    {
        // too expensive
        return;
    }

    if(currentCost > bestCost)
    {
        // New best combination! Save it.
        bestCost = currentCost;
        bestPurchaseSet = selected;
    }

    if(depth >= items.length)
    {
        // run out of food types
        return;
    }

    // if we do choose this item, then we mark it as selected and increase the cost of this order.
    search(items, selected | (0x1 << depth), depth + 1, currentCost + items[depth].cost, maxCost);

    // if we don't choose this item
    search(items, selected, depth + 1, currentCost, maxCost);
}
```

This should run quite efficiently, because each food item only adds one additional level of recursion - and many of the recursive branches are chopped off early (as soon as the purchase becomes too expensive).

Finally, it's a matter of printing out the results:

```
    System.out.print("Best order for $" + totalMoney + " is: ");
    for(int i=0; i<items.length; i++)
    {
        if((bestPurchaseSet & (0x1 << i)) != 0)
        {
            System.out.print(items[i].name + ", ");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The tip is " + (totalMoney - bestCost)/bestCost * 100 + "%");
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Your logic is pretty clear to me. But what did you mean by "I've also created class variables for the best case int bestPurchaseSet = 0;double bestCost = 0;" What does class variable mean? And what is &, << and 0x1?

Comment: A class variable is sometimes called a member variable. It's a variable which is accessible from all methods inside a class. & and << are both bitwise operators - & is a bitwise and, and << is shift left ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html ). 0x1 is the same as 1. The 0x prefix says that the following number is in hex, which is conventional when you're working with bit manipulation.